Why is the total time is off when combining MP3s with FFmpeg?
I have over a 1.5TB of audio books about 1/2 are MP3s.
I am combing MP3s and first I check the bit rate to be the all the same. Then I run and MP3 checker for file errors.
I have used multiple program mp3 cutter joiner and now FFmpeg.
When I combine the MP3s the total time is off, like 25% less, two 4h when combined was 6h. This was at command level and no changes to format. Also used FFmpeg batch AV converter. This happens about every 2 in 10 audio book combined. And yes the parts play just fine.
Why does this happen?

Are you playing these MP3s on a car stereo, or some other means? I have used the Voice audio player (Android) and it handles individual or groups of MP3 files for audio books. So I wonder if changing the tool you're using to play these audio books would be a better solution overall.

But, to the question you've asked: What is the ffmpeg command you're using the join these? What research have you done regarding this? When you test the MP3 files after do they play OK? What is missing? We need a lot more information before we'll be able to get you answers. Also, the first two paragraphs, though giving information that may help us question your entire premise, don't actually help the question itself, and I recommend you simply remove those. Use the EDIT button to fix and improve your question.

Are the files CBR or VBR?
